# Is it possible to have an underwater waterfall within an underwater air pocket?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics

Could water enter the top of an air pocket and be drained back into the ocean, without filling up the air pocket? I was thinking, since the water entering from above would not allow air from the air pocket to escape, it might be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not naturally.

There is no gravitational imbalance to drive a waterfall in the ocean.  The problem isn't filling up the air pocket.  It's the "drained back into the ocean" part.

Where is the water in an underwater chamber going to go?  If the chamber connects to the ocean, the pressure outside should be greater and water should be rushing in from below, filling the chamber and stopping the waterfall.  If the chamber does not connect, then the waterfall fills the chamber and then the water stops once it's full (maybe with an air pocket left at the top.)

---

Adding from some comments:

> Just so I’m understanding correctly: the water being driven down the pipe and into the air pocket would also bring extra air into the air pocket causing the air pocket to become over pressurized.

No.  I'm saying the water coming into to the chamber (even without any air) would tend to pressurize the chamber.  If water is falling in, it's because the pressure is higher outside than in.  As the water enters, that squeezes the air and increases the pressure.

The only way for that to not happen is if you have powerful pumps to evacuate the chamber at the same rate.  If you do, then the fact that you're underwater makes no difference.  This is then just a big sealed fishtank with a water pump.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What about for an artificial air pocket? Say you have an artificial underwater air pocket, with a pipe connected to the top that runs above water level. Now say that (somehow) there is a constant flow of water through the tube into the air pocket. Would the air pocket fill up?

Comment: Depends on how the water is being driven through the pocket.  If air is below the inlet, normally the chamber would pressurize and eventually the air would be forced back through the inlet.  But if you have pumps keeping the pressure low, that wouldn't have to occur.  Comes down to the design and execution.

Comment: Just so I’m understanding correctly: the water being driven down the pipe and into the air pocket would also bring extra air into the air pocket causing the air pocket to become over pressurized. As such, the air pressure in the pocket would eventually exceed the pressure within the pipe, causing some air to leak out. How would that cause the air pocket to fill up? And why would there then be a need to depressurize the air pocket? @BowlOfRed

Comment: If water is entering the air pocket at a constant rate, and leaving the air pocket at the same rate (dispersing into the ocean) wouldn’t the pressure within the air pocket remain the same?

Comment: Yes it would.  But you'd have to make that happen.  The title premise "underwater waterfall" seems to imply that being underwater and the pressures from it are relevant.  But if you're pumping the water out, then the fact you're underwater doesn't seem to mean much.  You've just constructed a system to pump water through a chamber at a fixed rate.  In such a case, the air will remain.

Comment: I’m not trying to imply that water is getting “pumped out”. And my question doesn’t do a good job of representing what I’m trying to figure out. Sorry about that. I’ll try to clarify. Say you have water constantly being fed down a pipe which runs to an underwater air pocket. The water drops from the outlet of the pipe — through the air pocket — and into the ocean. Would the air pocket fill up? Would the air pocket become overly pressurized? @BowlOfRed